# How to perform 301 redirect in Vue JS 3 using SSR

Tags: vue.js, express, redirect, vuejs3, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to implement a 301 permanent redirect in a Vue JS 3 application using Server-Side Rendering (SSR). I've tried using the `this.ssrContext.res.redirect` method, but it's not working as expected.

Here's the code I've tried in Vue JS:

```
import { useSSRContext } from 'vue/server-renderer';

data() {
  return {
    ssrContext: useSSRContext(),
  };
}

serverPrefetch() {
  this.ssrContext.res.redirect(301, 'http://google.com');
}
```

Express JS code:

```
await renderToString(app, context).then((appContent) => {
                fs.readFile(
                    path.join(distPath, '/client/index.template.html'),
                    (err, html) => {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }

                        appContent = `<div id="app">${appContent}</div>`;
                        html = html
                            .toString()
                            .replace('<!--vue-ssr-outlet-->', `${appContent}`)
                            .replace(
                                '{{{ renderState() }}}',
                                `${renderState(
                                    context.state,
                                    '__INITIAL_STATE__',
                                )}`,
                            );

                        const comptempl = _.template(html, {
                            interpolate: /{{{([\s\S]+?)}}}/,
                        });

                        const { pagedata } = store;
                        html = comptempl({
                            pagedata,
                        });

                        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

                        pluginOptions.ssr.renderToString(
                            pagedata,
                            err,
                            html,
                            req,
                            res,
                            projectType,
                            httpRequestDurationMicroseconds,
                            requestStarted,
                        );
                    },
                );
            });
        });
```

This code doesn't actually redirect the user to the specified URL. In the backend we are using express js.

Any suggestions on how to properly implement a 301 redirect in Vue JS 3 using SSR?